# What's the meaning of 下来 in 把它写下来？

Tags: translation, grammar

In the sentence "把它写下来", what's the meaning of “下来”？

Can I just say "把它写"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下来 is a result complement for the verb 写

把它写(下来) = write it (down)

把它写 is an incomplete sentence because the verb 写 doesn't sound complete

把它写在纸上 (write it on paper) would be a complete sentence

Please read [result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/result_complement) at Chinese Grammar Wiki

Comment: It’s a direction complement

Comment: 下 is a direction 下来 is a result (down on a surface) similar to 放下 (direction) -- 放下来 (completed the action 放下)